# Where is timedatectl information stored?

Tags: date, time, ntp

I am working on an embedded system without RTC battery. The time is synchronized via NTP when internet connection is available (which does not always happen). When the device is shut down, the time is reset to a past value. Sometimes I notice that this "default" value has been updated to a more recent one. Where is this information stored in the filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last known “good” timestamp is stored as the modification time of [`/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html#/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock). The minimum value used is the `systemd` build date. It is updated whenever time is synchronised successfully from a network source, and periodically if [`SaveIntervalSec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html#SaveIntervalSec=) is set (with [systemd 250](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v250/NEWS#L268) or later).

This means that by default you’ll see more recent timestamps during boot whenever:

- a newer version of `systemd` is installed
- the system managed to synchronise its time after the previous boot

Comment: My /var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock file is empty. Was does it mean? Also, where should I set SaveIntervalSec?

Comment: The file is supposed to be empty; the information it conveys is stored in its modification time. `SaveIntervalSec` is set in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`; the link in the answer points to a page with detailed instructions on how to set it.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the link. I set SaveIntervalSec but I got the error:
Unknown key name 'SaveIntervalSec' in section 'Time', ignoring
My linux environment has been created with Yocto. Is is possible that I have to update systemd?
As for the clock file: if I have other sources of synchronization, can I manually edit it at runtime?

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned that `SaveIntervalSec` was added in systemd 250, so you need at least that version. You can update the timestamp manually using `touch` or any equivalent tool, on a Yocto system it might be simpler to do that periodically rather than update systemd.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question: if I check the presence of `/run/systemd/timesync/synchronized` and then touch `/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock`, is this procedure correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.